# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on chrome for a specific site

Tags: google-chrome

We have a site which occasionally on chrome browser with "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET",i t happens for a while and it doesn't get fixed until I restart my browser.

This is happening for my users not me alone.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was the SSL Certificate binding. I select the correct Certificate in IIS binding.

Answer (score -1):

Causes of Err_Connection_Reset Chrome Browser error issue:

- Google Chrome Browser error problem.
- Your internet connection is interrupted or disabled.
- Firewall blocks specific websites.
- DNS probe finished no internet

So, in order to fix this error you can try these solutions below:

**Reset Internet Connection.**

**Disable DNS prefetching option.**

**Uncheck Use a proxy server for your LAN.**

**Delete browsing history**

This tutorial could help you: https://windows10freeapps.com/err_connection_reset-chrome-browser-error-windows-10/

Answer (score -1):

Reset Internet Connection.

Disable DNS prefetching option.

Uncheck Use a proxy server for your LAN.

Delete browsing history

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate (rather, a excerpt) of nam anh Lee's existing answer from 2017. Instead, if you agree with that answer, click the upvote arrow on the answer.

Answer (score -1):

**7 Method to fix the Err_Connection_Reset Error in Chrome Browser:**

1. Firstly Check Website and Browser/ System.
2. Check your Computer’s Proxy Settings
3. Clear your Browser Cache
4. Reset your IP/TCP Settings
5. Restart the Router.
6. Temporarily Disable the Firewall and Antivirus programs

If it is still not working then contact the internet provider. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: OP is asking how to solve this as a _developer_, not an end user.